# Are there any references in the Vedic Scriptures prohibiting the ostentatious and lavish style wedding ceremonies?

Tags: scripture, marriage

I wonder do Vedic scriptures speak of the simplicity required in the wedding ceremonies? And do they prohibit the lavish and ostentatious display of wealth  in marriage ceremonies?

Comment: Veda speak about liberty to women and spiritual aspects.   Here and there,  mention was made about persons,  who deviated from right path to Spirituality .

Comment: by vedic scriptures do u mean Hinduism scriptures in general including Puranas, Dharma Shastras etc.?

Comment: I mean the Kalpa Sutras or Dharma Shastras without including Puranas